# Routes from DB for nginx reverse proxy

Tags: postgresql, nginx, scripting, proxy

How to get routing data from external source for Nginx reverse proxy?

Project has multiple external file storages. Legacy code has following workflow:

1. File request comes to RoR controller
2. RoR gets external filename from model (Postgres)
3. RoR takes file contents from external source and returns it

It's very bad concept, so I suppose to change this logic to:

1. File request comes to nginx
2. Nginx gets external filename from some service/script, which has DB access
3. Nginx proxies file from external source by filename from (2)

So, question is how to take filename stored in postgres from nginx? I suppose, it will be alright to get it with http-request to localhost, but how to do this in nginx config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad concept. Good concept is

1. File request comes to nginx
2. nginx pass it to RoR
3. RoR gets external filename from model (Postgres)
4. RoR pass nginx new URI via `X-Accel-Redirect`
5. nginx serves file.

See http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile